# Every 10th row based on timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with signal name, value and timestamp. these signals where recorded at sampling rate of 1sample/sec. Now i want to plot a graph on values of months, and it is becoming very heavy for the system to perform it within seconds. So my question is " Is there any way to view 1 value/minute in other words i want to see every 60th row.?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` function to enumerate the rows, and then use modulo arithmetic to get the rows:

```
select signalname, value, timestamp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum % 60 = 0;
```

If your data really is regular, you can also extract the seconds value and check when that is `0`:

```
select signalname, value, timestamp
from table t
where datepart(second, timestamp) = 0
```

This assumes that `timestamp` is stored in an appropriate date/time format.

Comment: Thankyou, one more addition to the question, what if i am joining this table with other tables and others with others?

Comment: @Furqan . . . It should work.  But, you can also put the current query in a `with` statement to "separate" the two sets of logic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sampling, you could use the one minute average for your plot:

```
select  name
,       min(timestamp)
,       avg(value)
from    Yourtable
group by
        name
,       datediff(minute, '2013-01-01', timestamp)
```

If you are charting months, even the hourly average might be detailed enough.

Comment: you mean average of each 60 samples?

Comment: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. is the error.